# Generate random numbers chi-square distribution

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

I am trying to generate random integer values in the chi-squared distribution in Python. Below you can see my code.

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
  
# Using chisquare() method
gfg = np.random.chisquare(3, 1000)

df_chi = pd.DataFrame(gfg, columns = ['Column_A'])

df_chi.describe()
count, bins, ignored = plt.hist(gfg, 14, density = True)
plt.show()
```

This code generates random values in the chi-square distribution. Now I want to create random values in the chi-square distribution but some specific, such as:

```
minimum value =1 
maximum value= 100
standard deviation = 10
mean = 50
```

So can anybody help me how to solve this and generate a base with this characteristic?

Comment: Using the notation from [the wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chi-squared_distribution), where `k` is the degrees of freedom, the mean of the chi-squared distribution is `k` and the variance is `2*k`, so the standard deviation is `sqrt(2*k)`.  If the mean is 50, then the standard deviation must be `sqrt(2*k) = 10`.  So what you are asking for is not possible.  If you want something that is, in some sense, *approximately* chi-squared, then you'll probably have to be more specific about what you consider an acceptable approximation to be.

Comment: I changed SD in10. So now does it possible to create?